# How to marshal array to binary and unmarshal binary to array in golang?

Tags: go, encoder, decoder, gob

I want to use `gob` to `encode` and `decode` object, I do it like this:

```
type transProp struct {
    a []int
    b []float64
}

func (p transProp) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {
    // A simple encoding: plain text.
    var b bytes.Buffer
    fmt.Fprintln(&b, p.a, p.b)
    return b.Bytes(), nil
}

// UnmarshalBinary modifies the receiver so it must take a pointer receiver.
func (p *transProp) UnmarshalBinary(data []byte) error {
    // A simple encoding: plain text.
    b := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
    _, err := fmt.Fscanln(b, &p.a, &p.b)
    return err
}

func TestGobEncode(t *testing.T) {
    p := transProp{
        a: []int{3, 4, 5},
        b: []float64{1.0, 2.0},
    }

    var network bytes.Buffer
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&network)
    err := enc.Encode(p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("encode:", err)
    }
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(&network)
    var p1 transProp
    err = dec.Decode(&p1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("decode:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(p1)
}
```

But, this report error like this:

```
decode:can't scan type: *[]int
```

Comment: Println/Scanln aren't meant to be used for serialization. You could probably implement `fmt.Scanner`, but you might as well do it directly in the Marshal methods you have.

Answer (score 8):

If you can change the visibility of `transProp` fields to public, e.g.

```
type transProp struct {
    A []int
    B []float64
}
```

then you don't need to implement custom binary marshaller/unmarshaller. You can use default `gob` decoder/encoder.

However, if you can't, there are many options.

1. The simplest one, define another `wrapper struct` that export related fields, wrap `transProp`, then use default `gob` encoder/decoder, e.g.

   ```
   type wrapTransProp struct {
       A []int
       B []float64
   }

   func (p transProp) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {
       //Wrap struct
       w := wrapTransProp{p.a, p.b}

       //use default gob encoder
       var buf bytes.Buffer
       enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
       if err := enc.Encode(w); err != nil {
           return nil, err
       }
       return buf.Bytes(), nil
   }
   func (p *transProp) UnmarshalBinary(data []byte) error {
       w := wrapTransProp{}

       //Use default gob decoder
       reader := bytes.NewReader(data)
       dec := gob.NewDecoder(reader)
       if err := dec.Decode(&w); err != nil {
           return err
       }

       p.a = w.A
       p.b = w.B
       return nil
   }
   ```
2. Custom marshaller/unmarshaller with custom data layout. There are many implementation possibilities. Several considerations:

   - Byte order, little/big endian?
   - Packet/stream layout?

   An example implementation of `big-endian` with stream format:

   ```
   // Big-Endian
   // Size  : 4,         4,      1,        n,     4,       n
   // Types : uint32,    uint32, uint8,    []int, uint32,  []float64
   // Data  : #numbytes, #nInt,  #intSize, p.a,   #nFloat, p.b
   ```

   The challenge is in how to represent `int` since it's architecture dependent. Sample implementation will be:

   ```
   func (p transProp) MarshalBinary() ([]byte, error) {
       //Get sizeof int (in bits) from strconv package
       szInt := strconv.IntSize / 8
       nInt := len(p.a)
       nFloat := len(p.b)

       nStream := 4 + 4 + 1 + nInt*szInt + 4 + nFloat*8
       stream := make([]byte, nStream)
       pos := 0

       //total number of bytes
       binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(stream, uint32(nStream))
       pos += 4

       //num of items in p.a
       binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(stream[pos:], uint32(nInt))
       pos += 4

       //int size
       stream[pos] = uint8(szInt)
       pos++

       //items in a
       switch szInt {
       case 1:
           for _, v := range p.a {
               stream[pos] = uint8(v)
               pos++
           }
       case 2: //16-bit
           for _, v := range p.a {
               binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(stream[pos:], uint16(v))
               pos += 2
           }
       case 4: //32-bit
           for _, v := range p.a {
               binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(stream[pos:], uint32(v))
               pos += 4
           }
       case 8: //64-bit
           for _, v := range p.a {
               binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(stream[pos:], uint64(v))
               pos += 8
           }
       }

       //number of items in p.b
       binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(stream[pos:], uint32(nFloat))
       pos += 4

       //items in b
       s := stream[pos:pos] //slice len=0, capacity=nFloat
       buf := bytes.NewBuffer(s)
       if err := binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, p.b); err != nil {
           return nil, err
       }

       return stream, nil
   }

   func (p *transProp) UnmarshalBinary(data []byte) error {
       buf := bytes.NewBuffer(data)

       var intSize uint8
       var k, nBytes, nInt, nFloat uint32

       //num bytes
       if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &nBytes); err != nil {
           return err
       }
       if len(data) < int(nBytes) {
           return errors.New("len(data) < #Bytes")
       }

       //num of int items
       if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &nInt); err != nil {
           return err
       }

       //int size
       if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &intSize); err != nil {
           return err
       }

       //read int into p.a
       pos := 0
       stream := buf.Bytes()
       p.a = make([]int, nInt)
       switch intSize {
       case 1:
           for pos = 0; pos < int(nInt); pos++ {
               p.a[pos] = int(stream[pos])
           }
       case 2:
           for k = 0; k < nInt; k++ {
               p.a[k] = int(binary.BigEndian.Uint16(stream[pos:]))
               pos += 2
           }
       case 4:
           for k = 0; k < nInt; k++ {
               p.a[k] = int(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(stream[pos:]))
               pos += 4
           }
       case 8:
           for k = 0; k < nInt; k++ {
               p.a[k] = int(binary.BigEndian.Uint64(stream[pos:]))
               pos += 8
           }
       }

       //advance buffer
       buf.Next(pos)

       //num of float64 items
       if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &nFloat); err != nil {
           return err
       }

       //items in b
       p.b = make([]float64, nFloat)
       if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, p.b); err != nil {
           return err
       }

       return nil
   }
   ```

Comment: It is very nice to have a working [Un]MarshalBinary code like that. I was afraid of doing nonsense with such an approach, but your safeguards make it look robust enough. Thanks!